# linux running few scripts launch from a central script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have several bash script which contain in them infinite while loop.
I would like to run all of them from a single script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables

./agent_monitor.sh
./engine_monitor.sh
./kafka_monitor.sh
./zk_monitor.sh
```

what I get is that it stuck on the first script and it does not proceed to the next one to run them simultaneous.

Comment: `./agent_monitor.sh &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables

./agent_monitor.sh &
./engine_monitor.sh &
./kafka_monitor.sh &
./zk_monitor.sh &

echo "All scripts launched in background"
```

Notice the `&` symble at the end of each line, that tells it to run that task in background.